# Listening to incoming/outgoing calls in Oreo+ android devices without implicit broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

How do I listen to incoming/outgoing calls particularly these  implicit broadcast
`android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`
`android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`
In =>Oreo android system, these are not allowed to be consumed in the background even though both of them are allowed(i.e. not in exception broadcasts list)

I've tried:

`Registering both of the broadcasts in manifest.xml and giving runtime permission then works only while the app is in the foreground`

`Had a foreground service that context registers these broadcasts, this solution works fine but shows a constant notification, I don't want that`

> **Can anyone describe how TrueCaller or any such app is able to do so without notification?**
> Looking for solution which works even in if app is not being used